# Event not occur on the tab the first time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I use spring boot 2 with thymeleaf and bootstrap 4.

On a page, I have many tab (only web for the code below to reduce code...), i set one active.

When tab is displayed, but shown event not occur... To occur, I need to go to another tab and come back...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html th:lang="${#locale.language}">
    <head th:include="fragments/head :: HeadCss"/>
    <body>

        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
            <div class="row h-100">

                <div class="col-lg-2 my-auto">
                    <div th:replace="fragments/left-menu :: LeftMenu('configurations')"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="main" class="col-lg-10 main">

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#productTypesTabs" th:text="#{productTypes}">Product Types</a>
                        </li>

                        ...

                    </ul>


                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <div id="productTypesTabs" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active"><br>
                            <div id="productTypesFragment"></div>
                        </div>   
                        ...
                    </div> 

            </div>

        </div>

        <div th:replace="fragments/scripts :: Scripts"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("a[href='#productTypesTabs']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                    var url = '/template/producttypes';
                    $("#productTypesFragment").load(url);
                });
            });

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Is there missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if am not wrong when page is loaded first time there is no event fired so ntg loads

Your this code

```
  $("a[href='#productTypesTabs']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var url = '/template/producttypes';
        $("#productTypesFragment").load(url);
    });
```

Shouldn't be like this

```
function loadData(){
    var url = '/template/producttypes';
    $("#productTypesFragment").load(url);
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("a[href='#productTypesTabs']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        loadData();
    });


    loadData();   // loads when page is loaded first time
});
```